# stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth in Winform (C#) or WPF

Tags: c#, winforms

Thanks for reading, I'm iPhone dev, in iOS, when I need to stretch image but keep the "cap", I use stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth, but now I need to do with C# in winform, is there some similar function like this ?
Thanks

like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc241860(v=prot.10).aspx